# JS datatable automatically sum() inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm new to JS and trying to calculate automatically summ all data in all rows each time when use put some data in column "price"  and print

> **total var**

in console, but my code doesn't work. Any comments highly appreciated. Many thanks in advice

Here my simple table

```
<table id='example'>
     <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>id</th>
         <th>price</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td><input type='number' value="3"></td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td><input type='number' value="3"></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here my JS script

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#example').dataTable( {

   "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\₽,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };

        total = api
            .column( 1)
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

         console.log(total)

      }

   })

  })

  </script>
```

Comment: The problem here is that you're passing to the reduce() the input fields, rather than the values of the input fields, so you need to have one more level of filtering between the call to data() and reduce().  You can use something like map() to do something like: total = api.column(1).data().map(function (el) { return $(el).val(); }).reduce( function (a, b) { return intVal(a) + intVal(b); }, 0 )

Comment: Doug F, thanks a lot, but what if i have no value previously  in input field and then user put some data in their fields, how to listen inputs each time when user make some changes?

Comment: You could put a event handler on the fields that would listen to the "change" event that would do the same thing as your footerCallback function.  You can then make a generic function that both your footerCallback function and this event handler would both call so you don't repeat code.

Comment: Do you mean wrap in the function footerCallback? I try but nothing works. I add event listener on td  <td oninput="myfunc()"><input type='number'></td> and wrap footerCallback into myfunc(), but recieve error.

Comment: Doug F, could you help?

Comment: The main question how to call DataTables Api from a function, when I did it it cause an error «couldn’t reinitilize”